# What are the non-trivial solutions of $\sin a° \pm\sin b° = \sin c°$

Tags: trigonometry

The equation

$$
\sin(a°)  \pm\sin (b°) = \sin (c°) \quad \rm{where} \quad(a, b, c)∈\mathbb{Q^3}
$$

**Question**: Except for the degenerate case where one of a, b, c is zero or a multiple of 360, is there any other rational solution.

---

After sum-to-product, I got:

$$
2 \sin \left(\frac{a±b}{360}\pi\right) \cos \left(\frac{a∓b}{360}\pi\right)=\sin \left(\frac{c}{180}\pi\right)
$$

A special solution is:

$$ 
\cos\left(\frac{a∓b}{360}\pi\right)=\frac{1}{2} \quad \rm{when} \quad \frac{a±b}{360} = \frac{c}{180}
$$

So I got a set of special solutions:

$$
\begin{cases}
b = a \pm 120 + 720C\\
c = a \pm 60 + 360C\\
\end{cases}
$$

Are there other kinds of special solutions?

Comment: a=b=30 and c=90..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a common denominator and $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$, write your equation as $\sin(a \pi/n) + \sin(b\pi/n) + \sin(c\pi/n) = 0$, where $a,b,c,n$ are integers, $n > 0$.
If $\omega = \exp(i \pi/n)$, a $2n$'th root of unity, this says $\text{Im}(\omega^a + \omega^b + \omega^c) = 0$
and thus $\omega^a + \omega^b + \omega^c = \omega^{-a} + \omega^{-b} + \omega^{-c}$.
For any triple $(a,b,c)$ with, say, $a > b > c$, we can look at the factorization of
the polynomial $X^{2a} + X^{a+b} + X^{a+c} - X^{a-c} - X^{a-b} - 1$ and see if there are any cyclotomic factors.  For example, with $a = 18,\; b=17,\; c=7$ we have a cyclotomic factor $X^8 + X^7 - X^5 - X^4 - X^3 + X + 1$, the $30$'th cyclotomic polynomial.  Thus with $n=15$ we have $\sin(18 \pi/15) + \sin(17 \pi/15) + \sin(7\pi/15) = 0$.
Or, in terms of degrees, $\sin(216^o) + \sin(204^o) + \sin(84^o) = 0$,
which you might write as $ \sin(24^o) + \sin(36^o) = \sin(84^o)$.
Another nice one involves the $54$'th cyclotomic polynomial:
$\sin(32 \pi/27) + \sin(31 \pi/27) + \sin(13 \pi/27) = 0$, or $\sin(4 \pi/27) + \sin(5\pi/27) = \sin(13 \pi/27)$.

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple regular triangle in the trigonometric unit circle:
Writing this in vectors, you can easily see that:

$\overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} = \overrightarrow{0}$

[image]

Projecting this on the $Y$-axis, yields (for example, when you start at an angle of $10°$):

$\sin(10°) + \sin(130°) + \sin(250°) = 0$

Or, as $\sin(250°)=-\sin(70°)$ (because of $\sin(x) = -\sin(x±180°)$):

$\sin(10°) + \sin(130°) = \sin(70°)$

... or is this what you call "trivial"? :-)

Comment: As long as it does not contain multiples of 360, it is non-trivial, and it is a good way to understand it geometrically.